# Adding data to dropdown list from Azure database using ADO.net c#

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I need to take that data that I get from the select statement and put it in a dropdown box, but I do not know what to do after I have the select statement. This is my current code. I am using c# and ADO.net

```
protected void Possition1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var connection = new QC.SqlConnection("Server=CONNECTIONINFO"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var command = new QC.SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = DT.CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT * [firstName], [lastName]
                                    FROM [dbo].[Players]
                                    WHERE [position] = 'QB'
                                    ORDER BY [firstName] ASC";
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is error ?

Comment: Add `comma` after `*`.

Comment: what kind of application is this: windows web or wpf?

Comment: I am not getting an error, I just don't know how to get what is returned from the statement and put that data into a dropdown box

Comment: it is a web application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query can be executed using ExecuteReader() function , thus the result can be placed in a dataSet to fill the dropdown.. 
if its an Asp Mvc doprdown the list can be placed in form of SelectListItem as value an text in the similar form mentioned below

```
 string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Server=CONNECTIONINFO"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * [firstName], [lastName]
                                    FROM [dbo].[Players]
                                    WHERE [position] = 'QB'
                                    ORDER BY [firstName] ASC"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                ddlPlayers.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                ddlPlayers.DataTextField = "firstName";
                ddlPlayers.DataValueField = "PlayerId";
                ddlPlayers.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        ddlCustomers.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Player--", "0"));
```

I hope this would help